# Share a common file between two git directories

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I'm trying to build a custom web-app where I maintain two branches - a main and a development for staging. Both are stored as `/app-main` and `/app-dev` in our Azure VM server.

I want to maintain a JSON file as a shared resource between the two branches and directories. Our app is in-house and has a very small user base, so I just use the JSON to store user info and auth levels.

Currently if I want to add a user or edit an entry, I make changes to the file in my working branch (dev), commit it, PR and merge with main, and `git pull` inside both directories in the VM. This is very inefficient, and I'm looking for a more elegant way to execute this workflow.

Can I have a common file shared between the two that can update on all branches when one of them (let's say the JSON in dev) is updated? Or is there a completely different way to approach this?

Comment: Should the user database be under the same version control as the app? You could still use git, but make it a completely separate repository.

Comment: What would be a good way to access the separate repository from within the branches?

Comment: It mostly feels inefficient because it's either trivial to verify that your dev/staging service is still working, or you aren't checking it throughly enough before deploying to production as well. If you use CI, you can at least automate the deployment (eliminating the need to manually run `git pull`).

Answer (score 0):

Separate data and logic - move JSON into new special repo, which you'll link to the tree of "main" repo as subdirectory with git subtree

You'll get some headache with past (before split) history after it, but will get  "Modify once" benefit